# recuperar mensagem de erro do mysql com php

Tags: php, mysql

Bom galera, eu sei verificar o código de erro, porém não sei como recuperar a mensagem de erro.

Segue meu exemplo:

```
$conexao->query($query);
$erro = "Errorcode: $conexao->errno";
```

Quero fazer aparecer a mensagem e não o código. Como faço isso?

Comment: é ```errno``` mesmo ?

Comment: sim, ele retorna o código, preciso da mensagem de erro.

Comment: Ta usando ```PDO``` ?

Comment: não estou usando mysqli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deve ser a concatenação!

```
$conexao->query($query);
$erro = "Errorcode: ".$conexao->errno; //Assim aparece o numero do erro da mensagem
$erro = "Errorcode: ".$conexao->error; //Assim aparece a mensagem
```

Comment: Bom quero que aparece a mensagem e não o código. Dessa forma fica assim 'Errorcode: 1146'. Fica melhor se for a menagem de erro.

Comment: $erro = "Errorcode: ".$conexao->error;

Comment: blz, altera sua resposta ai por favor